# Python, multiple scripts, each with multiple threads running, how can one script determine when threads in other scripts are finished?

Tags: python, multithreading

For example, I have:

```
Script A
    thread 1
    thread 2

Script B
    thread 1
    thread 2
    thread 3
```

Say I want thread 3 in script B to wait until thread 1 in script A finishes before executing.  How is this done?  As far as I know I can't do a join(Script A,1) in Script B lol...  Thanks for your guidance .

Comment: Are you using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)? The same documentation explains a lot about synchronization.

Comment: by "script", you mean two different python processes are running?

Comment: @LiorCohen Yes.  scriptA.py and scriptB.py, each will have their own unique PID and are started separately by an autostart at boot.  These scripts are complex, and cannot be combined, it would be a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Synching between processes is not so straightforward and can be involved pitfalls like dead-lock etc.

In your case you just need to **signal a change of state** so you have the following options:

The simple yet primitive way - Process B wait (polling) for some agreed file existence that  process A should create, then process B delete the file. A slightly different version can be that process B polling on the update date of the file. The "shared" object here is the file. Again, primitive, but working.

Another pattern can be that process B opens a ** tcp socket** on some agreed port and wait (listen) for bytes to arrive from process A.

The most deep mechanisms is to use a **synchronization object** provided by the OS (and here come also differences between Linux and Windows) such as shared memory, pipes, message queues etc. You can read for example [here](https://opensource.com/article/19/4/interprocess-communication-linux-storage).

Comment: Yes!  I wasn't even thinking about it, but I already have ZMQ running on everything, for sending messages and video streams between multiple scripts and hardware nodes...  so actually, this should be easier than I was thinking.  THANKS!!!!!  Sometimes, we don't see what's right under our noses lol :)